Is it possible to predict terms from a GAM with partial newdata?
Is it possible to get predictions from a GAM object for specific terms from 'partial' newdata, which only provides values for the terms to predict? Running predict.gam with type = 'terms' for specific terms still seems to require me to provide "complete" newdata:
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> This is mgcv 1.8-42. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
library(data.table)

# some data for training a gam:
train = data.table(response = rnorm(100),
                   a = rnorm(100),
                   b = rnorm(100),
                   d = rnorm(100))

mod = gam(response ~ s(a) + s(b) + s(d),data = train)

newdat = data.table(a = -1:1,b = -1:1)

# this is not possible:
predict(mod,newdata = newdat,type = 'terms',terms = c('s(a)','s(b)'))
#> Warning in predict.gam(mod, newdata = newdat, type = "terms", terms = c("s(a)", : not all required variables have been supplied in  newdata!
#> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'd' not found

So the model expects newdata that has values for the predictand d, even though this is never used:
# adding any value for d works:
predict(mod,newdata = newdat[,d:=1],type = 'terms',terms = c('s(a)','s(b)'))
#>          s(a)         s(b)
#> 1 -0.14909452 -0.096316246
#> 2 -0.01305186  0.001326293
#> 3 -0.05200030  0.098968833
#> attr(,"constant")
#> (Intercept) 
#>  -0.0468407

# results do not depend on the value of d:
predict(mod,newdata = newdat[,d:=10000],type = 'terms',terms = c('s(a)','s(b)'))
#>          s(a)         s(b)
#> 1 -0.14909452 -0.096316246
#> 2 -0.01305186  0.001326293
#> 3 -0.05200030  0.098968833
#> attr(,"constant")
#> (Intercept) 
#>  -0.0468407

Created on 2024-04-03 with reprex v2.0.2
Specifically, I am working with several big GAMs with many different terms. The number and names of terms varies between the GAMs, but they have some shared terms for which I need to provide newdata. I am looking for a way to do this that does not depend on "the rest of the GAM" (e.g. names and number of terms), which is not actually used in the prediction.

add newdata.guarranteed  = FALSE

The comment by @langtang newdata.guaranteed = TRUE is the correct one. Just be very careful if you have factors in any of your actual models and ensure that the levels of those factors match what was used when fitting the model. If you don't get this right, mgcv won't warn you (because you now guarantee the data is correct) and you could well get nonsense results f the levels aren't specified correctly.

As pointed out by users langtang and Gavin Simpson, you can simply set newdata.guaranteed = TRUE:
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> This is mgcv 1.8-42. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
library(data.table)

train = data.table(response = rnorm(100),
                   a = rnorm(100),
                   b = rnorm(100),
                   d = rnorm(100))

mod = gam(response ~ s(a) + s(b) + s(d),data = train)

newdat = data.table(a = -1:1,b = -1:1)

predict(mod,newdata = newdat,type = 'terms',terms = c('s(a)','s(b)'),newdata.guaranteed = TRUE)
#>           s(a)        s(b)
#> 1  0.034319305 -0.32623950
#> 2  0.004482982  0.18215385
#> 3 -0.025353341 -0.04922302
#> attr(,"constant")
#> (Intercept) 
#>  0.04415271

Created on 2024-04-04 with reprex v2.0.2

If you aren't using d in your prediction then why not run without it
library(mgcv)
library(data.table)
# some data for training a gam:
train = data.table(response = rnorm(100),
                   a = rnorm(100),
                   b = rnorm(100),
                   d = rnorm(100))

mod = gam(response ~ s(a) + s(b),data = train)
newdat = data.table(a = -1:1,b = -1:1)
predict(mod,newdata = newdat,type = 'terms',terms = c('s(a)','s(b)'))

OUTPUT
          s(a)        s(b)
1  0.078532924  0.08331835
2 -0.005154494  0.05961488
3 -0.088841912 -0.13662222
attr(,"constant")
(Intercept) 
-0.06410168 


They say exactly why they can't run their models without d (or the equivalents in their actual setting).

Leaving out the other terms substantially changes the model, so that's not what I want. In the posted example, d and response are only independent for simplicity, which is the reason why leaving out d does not really impact the model.

I get the same prediction leaving d out of the gam() as I do using newdata.guaranteed = TRUE
